# Report Viewer ASP.NET - Debuggin is ok , when published load blank

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I have one doubt. When i'm debuggin, my code runs normally. I have a Report Viewer and he works fine. When a publish the system and report on server, the reportviewer load only header columns, with blank values. I have to install something on the server ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are your local system and the reporting server connecting to the same back end database?  It sounds like the report its self is functioning fine, but the server is seeing different data than when you run it locally.

Comment: Yes Bradley, the same database, with same datas. When i debug, i connect to the server database. I have two reports, one report works fine and the other one only header columns.

Comment: Which format is the report, `.rdl` or `.rdlc`?

Comment: When i run on server the message is.. " fail to validade FilterValue of Grouping " , but when debuggin the error not occour.